# Statefulness in eager mode vs non-eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an RNN that works in eager mode but not otherwise, and I'd like to understand why.

The RNN is supposed to accept a sequence of numbers and output their cumulative sum.  Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()

init_state_getter = lambda shape, dtype: np.ones(shape).astype(np.float32) # was ones

rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(
    1, # 1-dimensional state
    stateful=True,   
    return_sequences=True,
    activation=None, 
    use_bias=False,
    kernel_initializer = init_state_getter,
    recurrent_initializer = init_state_getter,
    return_state=False
)

x = np.ones([1,1,1]).astype(np.float32)

for _ in range(5):
    print(rnn(x))
```

and this works, we get the output

```
tf.Tensor([[[1.]]], shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[[2.]]], shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[[3.]]], shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[[4.]]], shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[[5.]]], shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Now let's modify this for not eager mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

init_state_getter = lambda shape, dtype: np.ones(shape).astype(np.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,1,1))

    rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(
        1, 
        stateful=True,   
        return_sequences=True,
        activation=None, 
        use_bias=False,
        kernel_initializer = init_state_getter,
        recurrent_initializer = init_state_getter,
        return_state=False
    )
    output = rnn(x)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    sess.run(init)


    for _ in range(5):
        print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={x:np.ones([1,1,1]).astype(np.float32)}))
```

This time, the RNN seems to keep losing its state, even though I am never re-initiazing:

```
[[[1.]]]
[[[1.]]]
[[[1.]]]
[[[1.]]]
[[[1.]]]
```

Now I think I could explicitly feed the old state into RNN as part of the feed_dict, but (1) I'm surprised that I need to do this, given that we've set stateful=True and (2) I have no idea how to fix this if I am using an estimator.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is that you are not passing the initial state during the RNN call. Here's how you can modify the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Session() as sess:

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,1,1))

    rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(
        1, 
        stateful=True,   
        return_sequences=True,
        activation=None, 
        use_bias=False,
        kernel_initializer = 'ones',
        recurrent_initializer = 'ones',
        return_state=True 
    )

    current_state = np.zeros((1,1))
    state_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 1])
    output, state = rnn(x, initial_state=state_placeholder) # You need to explicitly pass the state in the next step 
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for _ in range(5):
        op_val, state_val = sess.run([output, state], feed_dict={x:np.ones([1,1,1]).astype(np.float32),
                                                                 state_placeholder: current_state.astype(np.float32)})
        current_state = state_val
        print(op_val)
        # print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={x:np.ones([1,1,1]).astype(np.float32)}))
```