# GRU/RNN state in graph mode Vs eager execution mode

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have same piece of code written first in eager execution mode and then in graph mode. Now, I am not quite able to figure out why the GRU state is not retained in the graph mode while it's working fine in eager mode.

Here's the eager mode code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import xxhash
import numpy as np 
tf.enable_eager_execution()
rnn_units = 1024 
def hash_code(arr): 
    return xxhash.xxh64(arr).hexdigest()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        stateful=True,
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform', batch_input_shape=[1, None, 256])])

lstm_wt = np.load('lstm_wt.npy', allow_pickle=True) # fixed weights for comparison 
lstm_re_wt = np.load('lstm_re_wt.npy', allow_pickle=True)
lstm_bias = np.load('lstm_bias.npy', allow_pickle=True)
model.layers[0].set_weights([lstm_wt, lstm_re_wt, lstm_bias])

op_embed = np.load('op_embed.npy', allow_pickle=True) # fixed input 
op_lstm = model(op_embed)
print(hash_code(op_lstm.numpy()))

op_lstm = model(op_embed)
print(hash_code(op_lstm.numpy()))

model.layers[0].reset_states() # now reset the state, you'll get back the initial output. 
op_lstm = model(op_embed)
print(hash_code(op_lstm.numpy()))
```

Output of this code:

```
d092fdb4739588a3
cdfdf8b8e292c6e8
d092fdb4739588a3
```

Now, the graph model code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import xxhas
import numpy as np 

# checking lstm 
op_embed = np.load('op_embed.npy', allow_pickle=True)
# load op_embed, lstm weights 
lstm_wt = np.load('lstm_wt.npy', allow_pickle=True)
lstm_re_wt = np.load('lstm_re_wt.npy', allow_pickle=True)
lstm_bias = np.load('lstm_bias.npy', allow_pickle=True)

rnn_units = 1024 
layers = tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        stateful=True,
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(shape=op_embed.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
op_lstm = layers(x_placeholder)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
layers.set_weights([lstm_wt, lstm_re_wt, lstm_bias])
tf.assign(layers.weights[0],lstm_wt ).eval(sess)
tf.assign(layers.weights[1], lstm_re_wt).eval(sess)
tf.assign(layers.weights[2], lstm_bias).eval(sess)
print('keras op hash',xxhash.xxh64(sess.run(op_lstm, feed_dict={x_placeholder:op_embed})).hexdigest())
print('keras op hash',xxhash.xxh64(sess.run(op_lstm, feed_dict={x_placeholder:op_embed})).hexdigest())
```

output:

```
keras op hash d092fdb4739588a3
keras op hash d092fdb4739588a3
```

Any insights on how to fix this ambiguity and retain states in case of graph mode? 
There's a similar question asked before but unanswered. [Statefulness in eager mode vs non-eager mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650172/statefulness-in-eager-mode-vs-non-eager-mode)

Comment: I actually figured out the issue. I answered it on the link to the question I have it above.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the Solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650172/statefulness-in-eager-mode-vs-non-eager-mode) provided in the Question, for the **Benefit of the Community**.

The `Recurrent Neural Network` (`RNN` or `GRU` or `LSTM`) loses its `state` while executing it in `Non-Eager-Mode`/`Graph-Mode` by default.

If we want to retain the `state`, we need to pass the `Initial State` during `RNN` call, as shown below:

```
current_state = np.zeros((1,1))
state_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 1])
output, state = rnn(x, initial_state=state_placeholder)
```

Then, while executing the Output, we need to pass the `State` as well, in addition to the `Input` for `feed_dict`.

So, the code,

```
print('keras op hash',xxhash.xxh64(sess.run(op_lstm, feed_dict={x_placeholder:op_embed})).hexdigest())
```

can be replaced with

```
for _ in range(No_Of_TimeSteps):
        op_val, state_val = sess.run([op_lstm, state], feed_dict={x_placeholder:op_embed})).hexdigest(),
                            state_placeholder: current_state.astype(np.float32)})
        current_state = state_val
        print('keras op hash',xxhash.xxh64(op_val))
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!